# Issue calculating landmark covariances in EKF-SLAM

Tags: python, kalman-filter, slam-algorithm

I have recently implemented an extended kalman filter in python, that takes robot odometry and laser range finder inputs. However, it is not working as expected, so I've logged my covariance matrix each step to try and find faults.

I believe the issue is during the addition of the second landmark.

The following shows each step as I grow my P covariance matrix from zero landmarks to two landmarks. In this case, the robot first drives 53mm forward.

State vector, pre and post adding landmark seen at: 970mm range, 23 degrees.

```
[[ 53.]   | [[  53.        ]
 [  0.]   |  [   0.        ]
 [  0.]]  |  [   0.        ]
          |  [ 944.969203  ]
          |  [ 378.61846351]]
```

P, pre and post adding landmark covariance (Does RR appear cov correct? Given state ^):

```
[[  521.15  5141.15   521.15     0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]

[[  521.15  5141.15   521.15     0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.   530.85  5141.15       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.    2809.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
```

P, post adding Robot-Landmark and Landmark-Robot cross-variances.

```
[[  521.15  5141.15   521.15  521.15 5141.15       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [  521.15     0.       0.   530.85  5141.15       0.       0.  ]
 [  5141.15    0.       0.       0.    2809.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
```

State vector, post adding second landmark seen at: 813mm range, 53 degrees.

```
[[  53.        ]
 [   0.        ]
 [   0.        ]
 [ 944.969203  ]
 [ 378.61846351]
 [ 542.27561382]
 [ 649.29066967]]
```

P, post adding new landmark covariance and RL, LR cross covariances:

```
[[  521.15  5141.15   521.15  521.15 5141.15     521.15  5141.15]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
 [  521.15     0.       0.   530.85  5141.15       0.       0.  ]
 [  5141.15    0.       0.       0.    2809.       0.       0.  ]
 [  521.15     0.       0.       0.       0.     529.28  5141.15]
 [ 5141.15     0.       0.       0.       0.       0.    2809.  ]]
```

P, post adding the landmark-landmark cross variances, this is where things get weird:

```
[[  5.21150000e+02   5.14115000e+03   5.21150000e+02   5.21150000e+02 5.14115000e+03   5.21150000e+02   5.14115000e+03]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
[  5.21150000e+02   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   5.30850000e+02 5.14115000e+03   2.71597322e+05   0.00000000e+00]
[  5.14115000e+03   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00 2.80900000e+03   2.67931032e+06   0.00000000e+00]
[  5.21150000e+02   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.71597322e+05 2.67931032e+06   5.29280000e+02   5.14115000e+03]
[  5.14115000e+03   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.80900000e+03]]
```

For reference, this is how I calculate the above:

```
if self.lmCount > 0:
lrm = matmult(self.jacobianJXR, matmult(self.covRR, self.crossVarRM[0:3, 0:(self.lmCount*2)]))
self.covMM[self.lmCount*2:((self.lmCount*2)+2), 0:(self.lmCount*2)] = lrm
self.covMM[0:(self.lmCount*2), self.lmCount*2:((self.lmCount*2)+2)] = lrm.T
```

State of jacobianJXR:

```
[[ 1.  0. -0.]
[ 0.  1.  0.]]
```

What is causing the extreme values on the final section and do the previous steps appear normal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious; the first time you show your P matrix, it has a whole host of zeros. I hope you are only using the first 3x3 block of this P matrix in the filter until you see a landmark. The P matrix must always be positive definite. If not, the filter will diverge. Secondly, when you initialize the covariance of the landmark, it looks weird. Remember, it must be positive deifinite, which means it must be symmetric, unless you are applying a square root form of the filter, which I don't think you are. Check these two things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The algorithm has changed a fair bit since the post. However the covariances for the landmarks are constantly either tiny or huge. Often getting negative Eigen values.  

The covariance now grows like this: http://pastebin.com/xMNSuL24
And the filter: http://pastebin.com/1jHithjg (Line 134 adds the new landmark)

I checked and they appear to be symmetric in one reflection but not the other? Thoughts?

Comment: Sadly, I cannot go through the entire python code easily since I do not use it. When you see a landmark for the first time, what covariance do you assign to it? In other words, what covariance do you initialize a landmark with?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've parsed together the landmark creation code, and explained in detail  what is happening step by step here: http://pastebin.com/m0SHQCqg

Comment: Hi, you final step is the only one where you apply landmark-landmark covariances.  That explain why it is the first time you see this kind of result in the process.  I'm not surprised to find an "e6" result where you combine two "e3" landmarks values.  Those grown 5141.25 appear to be the reason.